# How do I use ng-model with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-model

I have a form created with ng-repeat. I am unsure how I incorporate that with ng-model. I have tried using track by $index.

I have found some examples on how I can use ng-model with values in an object, but I don't want to do that. I just need a way to uniquely identify a form input field with ng-model.

it seems like I would use something like:

```
ng-model="texting.vimeo_id[i]"
```

But that doesn't seem to do anything. Here is my full code:

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="(i, prospect) in texting.prospectList.Items track by $index">
    <td><a href="{{ prospect.prospectImageUrl.S }}"><img ng-src="{{ prospect.prospectImageUrl.S }}"></a></td>
    <td>{{ prospect.prospectFirstName.S }} {{ prospect.prospectLastName.S }}</td>
    <td>
      <div>
        <input ng-model="texting.vimeo_id" type="text" class="form-control" id="vimeo_id" placeholder="12345678" required>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button ng-click="texting.update_video_id($index)">
        Save
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the name of the item in your `ng-repeat` is prospect, so it would seem that you could just use `prospect.vimeo_id`, and it should see it

Comment: Not sure what Jared is asking but this is what I would have suggested.

Comment: I'm not trying to list anything that's in that list, so I don't want to see anything. I just need to differentiate it for when I do the ng-click